# Dynamically fill area under the polyline- svg

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas, polyline

I am getting the points dynamically, I have to fill the area under the polyline. I have tried the **fill** property but that would not result in what I have expected, screenshot attached.

```
     <svg
        viewBox={`0 0 ${points.length * 10} 100`}
        height="100%"
        width="150px"
      >
        <polyline fill="rgba(0,116,217,0.5)" stroke="#0074d9" stroke-width="5" points={points} />
     </svg>
```

the output is something like this

[image: the output is something like this]

and I want it to be something like this

[image]

I have already tried different solutions to that, like by using a **path** instead of using a polyline, but It is a little bit more complex if we have dynamic co-ordinates (points).

Comment: you may use the data for the starting `S` and ending `E` points of the polyline by adding `E.x, S.y` at the end of the points attribute

Comment: @enxaneta it resulted in something like [that](https://ibb.co/cr2TNSH)

Comment: show us a working code example

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could manually add points to your {points} list.
First point in your list should be `(0,0)` (as i understood that should be your bottom left).
And your last point should be `(max_x, 0)`, here you could easily use your last point to get `max_x`.

Then fill should do what you expected.

EDIT: This made the top of the table colored instead of the bottom one, thanks to @[Danny '365CSI' Engelman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2520800/danny-365csi-engelman) for pointing out you can simply invert that with `(0,max_y)` and `(max_x,max_y)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that is not working out for me really well.

Comment: What do you get as a result?

Comment: it resulted in something like [that](https://ibb.co/cr2TNSH), it's definitely better but not what I require.

Comment: so.. make it ``(0,max_y)`` and ``(max_x,max_y)``

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @enxaneta, you can just **prepend a starting and append an end point** to your array.

#### svg vs. cartesian coordinate system

**In svg the x/y origin is in the upper left**.

So you might need to **flip your y coordinates** as well to display your values in a  cartesian coordinate system.

See also: [Understanding SVG Coordinate Systems and Transformations (Part 1)](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/).

So your starting point would be:

```
let pointStart = [0, svgHeight];
```

#### Example

```js
let points = [
  [0, 10], 
  [10, 20], 
  [20, 50], 
  [30, 20], 
  [40, 10], 
  [50, 30]  
];

let svgHeight=100;
let svgWidth=(points.length-1)*10;
let strokeWidth= 5;
let pointStart = [0, svgHeight];
let pointEnd = [svgWidth, svgHeight];

// convert to mathematical (cartesian) coordinate system
let pointsFlipped = points.map(val=>{return [val[0], svgHeight-val[1]] });
points = pointsFlipped;

// add points:append end, prepend start
points.push(pointEnd);
points = pointStart.concat(points);

//adjust viewBox: 
svg.setAttribute('viewBox', [0, 0, svgWidth, svgHeight].join(' '));
polyline.setAttribute('points', points.join(' '));
```

```css
svg{
  border:1px solid red;
  max-height:70vh;
  width: auto;
  overflow:visible;
}


polyline {
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  paint-order: stroke;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 50 100" >
<polyline id="polyline" paint-order="stroke" 
fill="#5cb3ff" stroke="#0074d9" stroke-width="5" />
</svg>
```

Besides, you might need [`paint-order: stroke`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/paint-order) to avoid borders around the graph.
This property will render the stroke behind the fill area. This will require to use **opaque fill** colors.
In the example above, I've set overflow:visible to illustrate the effect.